# How do I show full names of folders that contain bookmarks in the Google Chrome Bookmark Bar?

Tags: ubuntu, google-chrome, bookmarks, google-bookmarks

I have Google Chrome installed on Ubuntu and I have made a number of folders of bookmarks placed within my bookmark bar.  The problem is that some of the folder's names are abbreviated like "Ru---" for "Ruby".  This is kind of annoying when I have more than one folder that starts with "Ru".  Also, my bookmark bar is not completely full, so there is plenty of space for these names to show.  Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Can you show us a screenshot? My bookmarks never truncate, regardless of the size.. Can you see the full name in bookmark manager?

Comment: Correction: truncates after ~20 characters

Comment: [Screenshot](http://i831.photobucket.com/albums/zz238/SeanMontana/Selection_024_zpsdcc417e6.png)

Comment: Isn't that odd?

Comment: Exceedingly. Did this change recently? My check was on windows. Need to get back home before I can check on linux, but its definitely not as bad as yours

Comment: [This bug from years ago](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=20495) seems remotely similar.. Have you tried changing themes?

Comment: Hmm, yes it must have something to do with my theme.  I'm actually using Gnome Classic for my Desktop environment, and I've messed around with the Gnome Tweak tool some and changed themes.  However, the problem remains.

Comment: I cant think of anything but 1) Different DE (Gnome shell / Unity) 2) different user.

Comment: AHA! Found it!  Using the Gnome Tweak Tool, there is an option under 'Fonts' called "Hinting".  I changed this from the default of "Slight" to "None".  Boom full names.

Comment: Thats awesome! You might want to add that as an answer, and accept it, for future visitors.

Comment: And report to chromium as a bug.

Comment: Yea, I'll add my answer after 6 hours, since I'm a new user apparently  there is a time limit to answer my questions.

Answer (score 1):

I found that this was a problem caused by some preferences in the Gnome Desktop environment.  Using the Gnome Tweak Tool, go to the sections called "Fonts".  There is an option there called "Hinting".  ["Hinting" wiki.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Font_hinting)  I changed it from "Slight", which was the default for me, to "None".

Comment: I have the same problem under Ubuntu 13.04. Unfortunately your solution didn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

I realise this is an old thread, but it still tops Google's search results for this issue. It's caused by font rendering in Gnome and Gnome-derived desktop environments such as Cinnamon.

Ignoring the font settings in Chrome (or Chromium), instead open the system settings from your main menu. Enter the font settings, and experiment with different sans fonts for the 'default font'. In my case, switching to droid sans stopped folders being truncated, but truncated links like 'Twitter' and 'YouTube'. I eventually found that 'Nimbus sans L' fixed everything, and it's now my default font.

However your mileage will vary dependent upon screen size and resolution, etc. Play around until you find a font that works and still looks good.