# Bookmark names ellipses on Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarks

Is there a way to show the full name of bookmarks that have really long names on the bookmark bar in Google Chrome? Currently they are being shortened by truncation with ellipses in a manner similar to the CSS property `text-overflow`:

[image]

Related: [How do I show full names of folders that contain bookmarks in the Google Chrome Bookmark Bar?](https://superuser.com/questions/541422/how-do-i-show-full-names-of-folders-that-contain-bookmarks-in-the-google-chrome)

However in that issue, the problem is described as a Linux-only issue whereas I am currently running Windows 8.

Comment: I also faced the issue today. But after 7 years also no answers. So I started a bounty.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no way of getting rid of those ellipsis and
make more space available for the bookmark names.
Some past tricks existed for making the font smaller, so fitting more
characters in the allocated space, but these were not very useful.

The only method I can suggest is to create folders in your bookmarks bar
and store the bookmarks in them.
The contents of the folder will appear in a drop down list once it is
clicked, and the names will appear in full:

[image]

You could have a mixture by leaving bookmarks with short names
in the bar and only put the ones with long names in the folder(s).

This idea is not perfect, but I don't know of a perfect solution to
this problem.